# How write out the form of this problem in partial fraction decomposition?

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

Can someone correct this for me? I thought I got it right, but no. First I factored the bottom to get (x-1)^2 and then I put it into A and B form.

[image]

Comment: Notice that the degree in the numerator is $\geq$ the degree in the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Try doing long division on $$\frac{x^4-2x^3+x^2+9x-5}{x^2-2x+1}$$
Then you should get $$\frac{x^4-2x^3+x^2+9x-5}{x^2-2x+1}=x^2+\frac{\dots}{\dots}$$
Then you can decompose the unknown fraction into partial fractions.

Comment: Correct, the polynomial part is missing!

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that part would matter in this question. I thought all I had to put was the A+B+.... part, thanks!